# How can I make a textView sit on top of the keyboard when pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, uitextview

I have a text view on the bottom of one of my views, and it would get hidden by they keyboard when it pops up if I didn't do anything. What I did was that when the keyboard is about to appear, the text view moves up 160 points. The problem is that it doesn't sit in the exact same place on every iPhone because of the different sizes. I would like to know if it was possible for the text view to sit say, 20 points on top of they keyboard, instead of pushing it 160 points up from its' origin.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"), name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification, object: nil);
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"), name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification, object: nil);

}

var isShown: Bool = false
var willHide: Bool = false

func keyboardWillShow(sender: NSNotification) {

    isShown = true

}

func keyboardWillHide(sender: NSNotification) {

    willHide = true

}

func textViewDidBeginEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if isShown == true {

        self.view.frame.origin.y -= 160

    }
}

func textViewDidEndEditing(textView: UITextView) {
    if willHide == true {

        self.view.frame.origin.y += 160

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the size of the keyboard from the notification object.

Something like this

```
NSDictionary* info = [sender userInfo];
CGSize kbSize = [[info objectForKey:UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey] CGRectValue].size;
```

You can read more about this here in [Apple Docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/StringsTextFonts/Conceptual/TextAndWebiPhoneOS/KeyboardManagement/KeyboardManagement.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009542-CH5-SW3)

Comment: I've been trying to make it work, but I'm getting an error that says on the first line "use of unresolved identifier aNotification"

Comment: @user4363124 Sorry. In your case it would be sender. Since the object you get is sender which is of type NSNotification.

Comment: Yeah I figured that out. I wasn't really paying attention but at least now I've got that worked out. Thanks for the help!